# How to use image as a password in nodejs

Tags: node.js, image

I want to make a image password authentication system in which I add my image and then compare with the database and authenticate in that way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've one idea on how to implement this but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing this. correct me if I'm wrong.

On Signup :-

1. Get the image from user while signup.
2. Convert the image file to base64 String.
3. Encrypt the base64 image string using bcrypt and store it in database.

On Login :-

1. Get the image from user
2. Convert it to base64 String
3. compare base64 String with existing encrypted string present in database using bcrypt.compare

Code (Not very accurate but you'll get the idea):-

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const imageToBase64 = require('image-to-base64');

exports.signup =async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    image: req.file.filename,
  });
};

// While Signup user
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (!this.isNew) return next(); // return if document is not new (not created first time)
  const base64String = await imageToBase64("path/to/file.jpg");
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(base64String, 12); // Store it in database
  next();
});

// While Login do the same steps as above and compare 
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  const imageFile = req.file; // Not sure about this but u got the point
   
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  const base64String = await imageToBase64(imageFile);
  const isPasswordSame = await bcrypt.compare(base64String, user.password);

  if(isPasswordSame){
    // Login the user
  }
};
```

Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: What does it mean UserSchema.pre('save...... Is it a middleware to execute before saving it or else ?

Comment: It's mongoose middleware which runs before saving the document. More one pre save middleware [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre)